# Is my understanding of this code correct/complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am maintaining a customer Classic ASP website, and some ASP.NET code was found in a specific place. I need someone to help me understand the meaning of each line, because I will have to replace this ASP.NET code with Classic ASP functions.

From my understanding, here is what the code performs:

1. Get the Request.QueryString "digest", and put it into a variable named "str"
2. Set the Response.ContentType to "text/plain"
3. Call the "HashCode" function with the "str" variable. This "HashCode" function does the following :
4. Create an instance of a SHA1 hashing engine, named "hash"
5. Create an instance of an UTF8 string encoder, named "encoder"
6. Compute the variable "combined", which have to be a byte sequence derived from the "str" parameter
7. Get the SHA1 hash of "combined"
8. Return the Base64-encoded value of the previously computed SHA1 hash of "combined"
9. Response.Write of this returned value.

I want to be sure I'm not missing anything else. Is my understanding full and complete?

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="digets" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class digets : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string str= context.Request.QueryString.Get("digest");

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(HashCode(str));
    }

    public static string HashCode(string str)
    {
        string rethash = "";
        try
        {

            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(str);
            hash.ComputeHash(combined);
            rethash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.Hash);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strerr = "Error in HashCode : " + ex.Message;
        }
        return rethash;
    } 

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. 
It will generate the hash using HashCode method and then write it to response.